# How to use Modal Pop up extender

Tags: c#, ajax

What I want is when the link button is clicked, the panel will pop.but when I click the link button.it does nothing. help! What is the best way to use modal pop up extender? am I using it wrong?

```
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <uc1:AssignTicketControl ID="AssignTicketControl1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
     TargetControlID="LinkButton1" PopupControlID="Panel1">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would arrange items as below

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
   TargetControlID="LinkButton1" PopupControlID="Panel1">
 </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
   <uc1:AssignTicketControl ID="AssignTicketControl1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</asp:Panel>
```